# Installing libssl-dev, libffi-dev on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, django

I tried using command `brew install libssl-dev libffi-dev` but it's not working for me.

Does anyone know how to install it on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Those packages don't exist on homebrew, they are packaged under a different name openssl and libffi.

```
brew install openssl libffi
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using MacPorts:

```
port install libffi

port install openssl
```

You can then locate the installed libraries using:

```
port contents libname
```

And use a symbolic link if Python expects to find the lib somewhere else, Eg:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/... [expected location, cf errors msg]
```